# PostgreSQL Scheduled Database Backup

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pgadmin

For scheduling a daily back up on a postgres database we execute the following command:

```
0 2 * * * /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_dump -Fp -b -U database_name \
          > $HOME/db_backups/database_name-`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.sql \
          2>> $HOME/db_backups/cron.log
```

After the code executes, the log says "invalid password". Is there a way to specify a password or avoid the requirement when creating a dump?

Also we  would like to retrieve the dump and pop it on separate Windows server  using pgadmin3. When restoring using pgadmin `dbase -> database restore` the 'OK' button is disabled and we are unable to restore the database.

Comment: Check the manuals for .pgpass - you can put login credentials in a file. I'm not sure I understand what the exact problem is with pgadmin I'm afraid. Are you saying you can't restore any backups to the Windows server, or just this particular one?

Answer (score 2):

#### Backup without password

If you run the script as **OS user `postgres`** it should not request a password in a standard setup, because password-less `peer` access (or `ident` on older versions) is enabled in [**`pg_hba.conf`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) for the postgres user.

So make it a cronjob of postgres if you can. Or enable password-less access for the OS user running the job. You can do that in `pg_hba.conf` but, as @Richard already pointed out, the [password file `.pgpass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html) file may be a more elegant solution.

More on how to connect without password in [this related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14740/3684).

#### Restore in pgAdmin

I quote the [pgAdmin3 FAQ](http://www.pgadmin.org/pgadmin3/faq/):

> pgAdmin III uses PostgreSQL's pg_restore tool, which supports only the
>   COMRESS and TAR options of pg_dump which is used for backup creation.
>   The PLAIN format can't be interpreted by pgAdmin III and pg_restore
>   (it can be edited manually, and executed with psql and pgAdmin III's
>   query tool in many cases), and thus isn't accepted as valid file.
>
> We recommend using the COMPRESS format for daily backup tasks. The
>   PLAIN format is for advanced manual processing before executing as SQL
>   script, and has some restrictions (no blobs) which makes it less
>   usable for standard backup tasks.

To restore a plain SQL backup execute it with [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) similar to this:

```
psql mydb -p 5432 -U myuser -f backup.sql
```

For a single database backup you have to connect to the right database. For a cluster-backup with `pg_dumpall`, you might as well connect to the maintenance db "postgres".

You could also load and run such a backup with the pgAdmin query tool. It's plain SQL.