# How to use psql with no password prompt?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I wrote a script to `REINDEX` indexes in a database. Here is one of them:

```
echo -e "\nreindex for unq_vbvdata_vehicle started at: `date "+%F %T"`" >> ${LOG_FILE}
psql -U ${USERNAME} -h ${HOSTNAME} -d ${DBNAME} -c "REINDEX INDEX scm_main.unq_vbvdata_vehicle;"
if [[ ${?} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "reindex for unq_vbvdata_vehicle finished at: `date "+%F %T"`" >> ${LOG_FILE}
else
    echo "reindex for unq_vbvdata_vehicle failed" >> ${LOG_FILE}
    exit 1
fi
```

The problem is I can not run this script in standalone mode. `psql` is prompting password every time it runs. There is also two limitations:

1. I can not create a user on database with no password.
2. Because `REINDEX` locks tables, I should use `sleep <num>` between each `REINDEX`.

Is there any automatic solution?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You have four choices regarding the password prompt:

1. set the PGPASSWORD environment variable. For details see the manual: 
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html
2. use a .pgpass file to store the password. For details see the manual: 
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html
3. use "trust authentication" for that specific user: 
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-TRUST
4. use a connection URI that contains everything: 
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#AEN42532

Comment: Since PostgreSQL 9.1 there is also the `peer` authentication method for local connections. Currently only for Linux, BSD, OS X or Solaris (not Windows).

Comment: A note on the `.pgpass` option, you still have to specify username, database, and hostname (if you would've normally) in the `psql` command

Comment: with respect to 3, you need to edit the method. its explained here: https://gist.github.com/p1nox/4953113

Comment: Easily use `export PGPASSWORD="your_pw"` to go version 1

Comment: @gies0r I would never `export` a password because of security considerations

Answer (score 49):

A simple example with `PGPASSWORD` will be something like:

```
PGPASSWORD=YOUR_PASSRORD psql -h YOUR_PG_HOST -U YOUR_USER_NAME
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Ian_H, thank for your comments and I all agree with your points. The accepted answer is very comprehensive and that did solve my problem. The reason I put my answer to this old post is because it is still not straightforward to me, as I believe others may have the same feeling.

Comment: This was definitely a good addition to the accepted answer - helpful reminder that we don't need to permanently set ENV vars.

Comment: Note, that this would still expose your password to the command shell history.

Comment: Don't forget to restart your command prompt on Windows if you're adding this permanently to Path.

Comment: @StefanHaberl raises a good point. Using `read` can help (e.g., `read -s -p "Enter password: " PGPASSWORD; export PGPASSWORD`; see more at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56861186/1498178)).

Answer (score 5):

Depending your account permissions, the example without specifying the database may fail, because user permissions are checked against the database you connect to. It is better explicitly specify the database too.

```sh
# this can fail.
PGPASSWORD=YOUR_PASSRORD psql -h YOUR_PG_HOST -U YOUR_USER_NAME    

# this is more likely to work, assuming given account has permissions to that database.
PGPASSWORD=YOUR_PASSRORD psql -h YOUR_PG_HOST -U YOUR_USER_NAME -d YOUR_DATABASE
```

Answer (score 5):

In **Windows** you can set it system wide:

```
SETx PGPASSWORD YourPassword /M
```

Or for security if you don't want it system wide you can login in one line:

```
set PGPASSWORD=YourPassword&& psql -d database -U user
```

Answer (score 2):

Way-1:

```
PGPASSWORD="<password>" psql -U <db_user> -d <db_name> -h <host_name/domain> -p <port>
```

Way-2:

```
psql postgres://<db_user>:<user_password>@<hostname/domain>:<db_port>/<db_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful answers in this thread. I'm just adding this for ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo PGPASSWORD=yourpasswordHere -u postgres psql
```

This will take you into the postgres without the password prompt, without having to set any environment variables. This is not a permanent setting.

Comment: Don't do this: The password will be visible in the output of ps -ef.

Answer (score -2):

```
 var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 processStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["PGPASSWORD"] = "password";
 Process proc = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

It will work.

Comment: I pointer or two about how to actually make this work would be helpful.  For instance, you'd need Visual Studio 2019, and would need to create a solution, with a C# console project, etc, etc.

Comment: Ok, maybe missing what was written by Hannah but still very helpful for me :-)