# How to execute multiple postgres script from command prompt

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, psql

I have 100 script files which has insert scripts for the table. How can I execute these?

```
Scrip1.sql , script2.sql, script3.sql .... script100.sql
```

To execute single file, I am using the below command. But how can I execute all files?

```
psql -d DBName -p 5444 -U schemaname -f P_Scrip1.sql  2> err.log
```

Comment: Create one file that calls all the others.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to provide a password, it's easy:

```
for FILE in `ls -1 *.sql`
do
  psql -d DBName -p 5444 -U schemaname -f $FILE  2>$FILE.err.log
done
```

If you need to provide a password, concatenate all of the files together, then run `psql`:

```
for FILE in `ls -1 *.sql`
do
  cat $FILE >> /tmp/allfiles.sql
done

psql -d DBName -p 5444 -U schemaname -f /tmp/allfiles.sql 2>allfiles.err.log

rm /tmp/allfiles.sql
```

Comment: i need to provide password ...

Comment: @asalthangam: providing a password for that is a different question then "how do I run 100 SQL scripts" - see here for an answer to that: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Linux you can use the following script

```
for ((i=1;i<101;i++)); do psql -d DBName -p 5444 -U schemaname -f P_Scrip${i}.sql 2> err.log & done
```

Comment: file name is not unique . it is aa.sql , bb.sql ma.sql like that

Comment: I wrote the script based on the information on the question, based on your comment, my solution will not work. Phil answer will do the trick.