# How to prevent asking for password when creating new database in PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-10, ddl, command-line

I use the following batch file to create a new database in PostgreSQL 10.

```
echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\10\bin"
createdb -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres myDB
```

But it asks to enter the password. How to prevent asking for the password? I tried the `-w` option explained in [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_create_database.htm) to not ask for password prompt. But this did not work. How to prevent asking for password?

Comment: I tried the [pgpass file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html) method but it did not work. But how does "manage pg_hba.conf" file method work?

Comment: The pgpass file solution **does** work. See also [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable,

```
@SET PGPASSWORD=something_secret
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE mydb" -U postgres postgres
```

or just use a connection string

```
psql -c "CREATE DATABASE mydb" "user=postgres dbname=postgres password=something_secret"
```

Comment: I see that you have given two database names, `mydb` and `postgres` (`dbname=postgres`). Does this mean the database `mydb` comes under `postgres`?

Comment: @CodenameK: to create a database (mydb) you must first be connected to another database (postgres in the above example). It does not imply a hierarchy of databases.

Comment: [Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) we can read about `PGPASSWORD`: "Use of this environment variable is not recommended for security reasons, as some operating systems allow non-root users to see process environment variables via ps; instead consider using a password file".

Comment: true: service or password files are a more secure solution - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/libpq-pgpass.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/libpq-pgservice.html

Answer (score 1):

You may enter this line in the pg_hba.conf file like this:

`# TYPE DATABASE USER         ADDRESS   METHOD
   local   all      postgres               peer`

This is for running commands from the machine.
This passwordless login from local computers only
If you are on Windows any user can put a switch -U postgres and connect to the machine as superuser.
Do that only for development purposes.

Comment: `peer` is documented as **not supported on Windows** as of PG10. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PEER

Comment: I need to check my windows instalation hiw it works. I am running linux lately.

Comment: `peer` requires `local`, which implies `unix domain sockets` a feature not available on windows SFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using TCP connection and not socket connection.

I just tried on Windows 7 this command and work normally:
`createdb -U postgres test`
I hope that you notice that there is no **`-h localhost`**
Since `-p 5432` is default you can omit that also. 
I checked that pg_hba.conf doesn't have the configuration using `peer` but it works anyway.