# How to use psql command with no password prompt?

Tags: scripting, psql

I'm trying to write shell script to avoid entering password every time while login to psql.

Comment: I found the answer from here --> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from here & worked for me --> [How to use psql with no password prompt?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14740/how-to-use-psql-with-no-password-prompt)

PGPASSWORD=YOUR_PASSRORD psql -h YOUR_PG_HOST -U YOUR_USER_NAME